# Relative private access specifier in java?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, nested, private

If we declare a private instance variable in a class,then that variable is only visible inside only that class,if we want to access it then we have to make member functions for it,that is,the object of that class is not able to access it directly...
For e.g.,int this code...

```
    class A {
       private int a;

       public int getA() {
          return a;
       }
    }

    class B extends A {
void display()
{
       System.out.println(a);//error,trying to access private variable
       A obj=new A();
       System.out.println(obj.a); //Even object is not able to access it directly
       System.out.println(obj.getA());//Fine,it can access
    }
}
```

But why in case of inner class,the object of outer class is able to access the private variable of inner class directly through objects...for e.g.-

```
    class Outer {
void method1()
{
       System.out.println(y); //Error,can't access private member of Inner
       Inner obj=new Inner();
       System.out.println(obj.y); //Why this doesn't show error 
}

       class Inner {
          private int y;
       }
    }
```

Why this kind of privilege is provide to the outer classes in java???

Comment: Neither of those two code blocks compile; you have `println` statements outside of any functions or methods.

Comment: Yes, a starting point for a question like this would be code that compiles and, when run, does what you say it does.

Answer (score 0):

Because an *inner class* is a member of its enclosing class and therefore has access to other members of the enclosing class, even private ones, just like other members of the class do.

The converse of this is explicitly listed in the [Java tutorial on nested (including inner) classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html):

> ...is a member of its enclosing class. **Non-static nested classes (inner classes) have access to other members of the enclosing class, even if they are declared private.** Static nested classes do not have access to other members of the enclosing class. As a member of the OuterClass, a nested class can be declared private, public, protected, or package private. (Recall that outer classes can only be declared public or package private.)

*(My emphasis.)*

But the direction you're describing, where the outer class accesses the inner class's private members, is also allowed, and for the same reason: All of the members of a class have access to other members of the class.